# reactjs get selected option custom attribute

Tags: reactjs

I have a generated select, I'm looking to get the value + a custom attribute from the selected option, so far, I have it only getting the value.

```
    var ServiceProviderList = React.createClass({
      getInitialState: function(){
        return {
          service_provider_list: this.props.service_provider_list,
          quickbooks_vendor_id: '',
          currency: ''
        };
      },
      handleChange: function(e){
        this.props.onUpdate(e);
      },
      render: function(){
        var serviceProviderNodes = this.props.service_provider_list.map(function(item, index){
          return(
            <option key = {item.service_provider_id} value={item.quickbooks_vendor_id} data-currency={item.currency}>{item.company_name}</option>
          );
        }, this);
        return(
          <select value={this.props.quickbooks_vendor_id} data-currency={this.state.currency} id="quickbooks_vendor_id" name="quickbooks_vendor_id" required="required" onChange={this.handleChange}>
          <option value=""></option>
            {serviceProviderNodes}
          </select>
        );
      }
    });
```

**Parent:**

```
...
handleInput: function(e){
  this.state.invoice[e.target.id] = e.target.value;
  this.props.onInvoiceInput(e.target.id, e.target.value);
},

...
render: function(){
...
<div className="formRow">
  <label>Service Provider: </label><br /><ServiceProviderList id="quickbooks_vendor_id" service_provider_list={this.state.service_provider_list} onUpdate={this.handleInput} quickbooks_vendor_id={this.state.invoice.quickbooks_vendor_id} currency={this.state.invoice.currency}/>
</div>
```

**handleInvoiceInput (in root element):**

```
handleInvoiceInput: function(id, val){
  this.state.invoice[id] = val;
  this.setState({invoice: this.state.invoice});
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access a custom attribute by using: `getAttribute('attributename')`

```
handleInput: function(e){
  // e.target.getAttribute('data-currency'); will contain the selected currency.
  this.state.invoice[e.target.id] = e.target.value;
  this.props.onInvoiceInput(e.target.id, e.target.value);
},
```

Comment: I tried this but I keep getting an empty variable, am I doing something wrong elsewhere in the code?

Comment: When you inspect your DOM, does data-currency have a value in the rendered <option>?

Comment: the individual options have a currency value, but not the select itselt, when I do a console.log(e), it prints the entire select element.